# js.erb template won't get rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code.

```
def exception_handler(e)
   flash.now[:error] =  e.message
   render 'shared/exception_handler'    
end
```

here is the exception_handler.js.erb

```
$('#flash').html(' "/shared/flash_messages" )%>');
window.scrollBy(0,-10000);
$('#flash').slideDown('slow').effect('highlight', {}, 3000).delay(4000).slideUp('slow');
```

How can I get it running when I rescue an exception in controller. The strange thing is it was working before I made some changes in the code this morning.

Comment: Think you have to put your code in `respond_to` block without rendering template

Comment: or try to rename template as `_exception_handler.js.erb`

Comment: dont rename your template as `_exception_handler.js.erb` files with _ are partials. I think it is just missing the responds blocks like kishie said before

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you deleted this part

$('#flash').html('**<%=escape_javascript(render :partial=>** "/shared/flash_messages" ).html_safe %>');

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.js.erb` explicitly like this:

```
def exception_handler(e)
   flash.now[:error] =  e.message
   render 'shared/exception_handler.js.erb'    
end
```

then, you need to rename `exception_handler.js.erb` to `_exception_handler.js.erb`